# How do I retrieve textbox from an embedded form in a tabpage?

Tags: c#, forms

Im fairly new to C#, I have a parent form (form1) with a tabcontrol. the first tab is static and i have some stuff in there. After that i can dinamicaly add embedded forms (all the same form2) on the tab with a button. The newly created forms each have a single textbox from which i want to retrieve the textboxname.Text and write it on a textbox outside the tabcontrol in form1..

in form2 i added
public TextBox TextBox1
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1;
            }
        }
and in form1 the private Form1 otherForm; ...

but i dont know where to go from there i think i have to do a foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages) but im not sure ^^

Comment: when you wanted to read the values of the textboxes in the tabs, you can find the parent control for the static form and then call the `findcontrolsbyname` and then iterate through the list and then get its values and display in the static page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out...the key is you need to CAST the control in the TabPage back to Form2 before you can access the property you added to it:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab != null)
        {
            if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0] is Form2)
                {
                    Form2 f2 = (Form2)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
                    label1.Text = f2.TextBox1.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```